# JSF2.0 - Composite component with optional method expression

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6, composite-component

I'm implementing a composite component and I found a issue which I didn't find a solution.

I specified its attributes that can or not be passed by the page author, but I couldn't specify a method attribute (a method expression to Action) that, if it wasn't passed, the composite component doesn't use the method attribute in the composite:implementation tag.

Here my code:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="namePrompt" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="actionMethod" method-signature="java.lang.String  action()" required="false"/>
    <composite:attribute name="showComponent" default="false"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div>
       <p:commandLink actionListener="#{cc.attrs.actionMethod}"
                      rendered="#{cc.attrs.showComponent}"
                      >
            <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.namePrompt}"/>    
       </p:commandLink>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

When using it, I didn't specify the "actionMethod" attribute. Like this:

```
<util:foo namePrompt="SomeName" showComponent="true"/>
```

But I get the error message:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to resolve composite component from using page using EL expression '#{cc.attrs.actionMethod}'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can pass optional attribute to `actionListener`. What is you use case, what do you think it should happen when `actionListener` is not resolved and `commandLink` is rendered?

Comment: Yes the link component is rendered, but when the click action happens in the link Component it complains that I have not defined a method for attribute actionMethod. But that is my intention, sometimes I don't want to define a action method for the actionMethod attribute. Is this possible? I thought putting the 'required = false' solve the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to create two `p:commandLink` elements and render them conditionally according to definition of your parameter:

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{cc.attrs.actionMethod}" rendered="#{!empty cc.getValueExpression('actionMethod') and cc.attrs.showComponent}">
  <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.namePrompt}"/>
</p:commandLink>
<p:commandLink rendered="#{empty cc.getValueExpression('actionMethod')}">
  <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.namePrompt}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 7):

Change the method signature return type to java.lang.Object and add "null" as the default value.

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="namePrompt" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="actionMethod" method-signature="java.lang.Object action()" required="false" default="null"/>
    <composite:attribute name="showComponent" default="false"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div>
       <p:commandLink actionListener="#{cc.attrs.actionMethod}"
                      rendered="#{cc.attrs.showComponent}"
                      >
            <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.namePrompt}"/>    
       </p:commandLink>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

Without method:

```
<util:foo namePrompt="SomeName" showComponent="true"/>
```

With method:

```
<util:foo actionMethod="#{someBean.someMethod()}" namePrompt="SomeName" showComponent="true"/>
```

Comment: If using `action` instead of `actionListener` (as one typically should) this results in a FacesMessage warning `Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '...' for action '#{...}' with outcome 'null'`. So you have to use `actionListener` for this. (Mojarra 2.3.3.SP1)

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov: try `void action()` instead.

Comment: @BalusC, but wouldn't that also prevent an outcome from being considered, when there is an actual action method returning it?

Answer (score 4):

An other solution is to create an own component type, with a action method. Example:

```
<composite:interface componentType="myButton">
    <composite:attribute name="namePrompt" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="actionMethod" method-signature="java.lang.String  action()" required="false"/>
    <composite:attribute name="showComponent" default="false"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div>
       <p:commandLink actionListener="#{cc.action()}" rendered="#{cc.attrs.showComponent}">
          <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.namePrompt}"/>    
      </p:commandLink>
   </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

And the componentType has to look like:

```
@FacesComponent("myButton")
public class MyButton extends UINamingContainer {

    public MyButton () {
    }

    public String action() {
        MethodExpression me = (MethodExpression) this.getAttributes().get("actionMethod");
        if (me != null) {
            Object result = me.invoke(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(),     null);
            if (result instanceof String) {
                return (String) result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same exact error and needed to have an optional action method on my component too.

So I have tried adding a default parameter on the composite attribute with the method-signature, pointing to a method on the corresponding FacesComponent class and it works great!

Component:

```
<composite:interface componentType="myButton">
    <composite:attribute name="namePrompt" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="actionMethod" method-signature="java.lang.String  action()" required="false" default="#{cc.dummyAction}"/>
    <composite:attribute name="showComponent" default="false"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div>
       <p:commandLink action="#{cc.attrs.actionMethod}"
                      rendered="#{cc.attrs.showComponent}"
                      >
            <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.namePrompt}"/>    
       </p:commandLink>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

FacesComponent class:

```
@FacesComponent("myButton")
public class MyButton extends UINamingContainer {

    public MyButton () {
    }

    public String dummyAction() {
       return "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid puting methods inside composite. If tou need to do that, put the class that have the method inside composite, and use it like this:

```
<composite:interface>
   <composite:attribute name="classWithMethod" 
                        method-signature="java.lang.String"/>
</composite:interface>
```

And the implementation:

```
<composite:implementation>
   <div>
      <p:commandLink 
         actionListener="#{cc.attrs.classWithMethod.actionMethod}">    
      </p:commandLink>
   </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

Worked for me! :D